# Amazon S3 Bucket URL's fails to load some files programmatically

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 Bucket  url's fails to load some files, while these files are browsed directly in browser it's loading fine. No issues at all. What I am trying to do is create a pdf from html using a library called wkhtmltopdf programmatically using PHP.

The bucket I am trying to access is publicly accessible. Some of these files which are failing is also not the same ones as the previous, it keep's on changing every time. So I am not able to tag any doubts on it. When I checked regarding the  limits of requests to an Amazon S3 bucket, can send up to 5500 requests per second. And here in my case am sending a request of 1600 that's all images files.

Below is my code.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(120);
require './aws-autoloader.php';

require './Aws/S3/S3Client.php';
require './Aws/Exception/AwsException.php';

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
]);

?>
<html><body>

<?php 
$response = $s3 ->listObjects(array('Bucket' =>"my-example-bucket"));


$data = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod laboriosam atque, consequuntur beatae fugiat in incidunt perspiciatis dolorem ipsum nam itaque animi nobis quam illum dolore. Nam nostrum maiores, ipsa.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa vero veniam sed ullam commodi! Accusantium, officia vitae, adipisci mollitia, blanditiis voluptates accusamus nam atque repellendus laborum, ullam vel eligendi esse?</p>';

foreach($response['Contents'] as $key => $value) {
    
    $image = '';
    
    $path = $value['Key'];
    $image = "https://my-example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/$path";
    $data.='<img src="'.$image.'" width="100">';
    
?>
    
<?php           
}
$data.='</body>
</html>';


file_put_contents('C:\Users\Administrator\Demo\htdocs\test.html', $data);


exec('C:\"Program Files"\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf ./test.html ./test.pdf> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\my.txt 2>&1');
?>


</body></html>
```

Comment: are you getting same error when you try to add to html page?

Comment: I am trying to generate pdf with a 1000 and above images and these all stored in s3 bucket. Out of these some files are always fails to load. Error files will be different each attempt.

Comment: can you try with out pdf just show images in the html page, to find out the actual cause

Comment: without pdf all the images are coming fine

Comment: Okey then there is an issue with the pdf, the library don't support all these images

Comment: There must be some limit, i also face same issue with MPDF using aws images, the php library for images memory exceed the limit the it fails, consume all cpu power

Answer (score 0):

The listObjects method can't retrieve more than 1000 documents.
You need to use the getPaginator method as explained in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingPHP.html

```php
$results = $s3->getPaginator('ListObjects', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed the below command to get all the files downloaded before starting to generate the pdf and  now its taking  only one minute to download almost 1650 image files of average size and in less than 2.5 seconds pdf is generated.

Below is my updated code

```
<?php
set_time_limit(300);


require './aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
]);

try {
    // Get the object.
    $response = $s3 ->listObjects(array('Bucket' =>"my-example-bucket",'MaxKeys' => 1600, 'Prefix' => 'example-prefix/'));
    
   
        
   exec('aws s3 cp s3://my-example-bucket/example-prefix/ C:/xampp/htdocs/test-folder/downloads/example-prefix/ --recursive > ./log.txt 2>&1');
   $data = '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>';
    foreach($response['Contents'] as $key => $value) {
        $path = $value['Key']; 
        $data.='<img src="http://localhost/test-folder/downloads/'.$path.'">';
    }
$data.='</body></html>';
file_put_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\test-folder\test.html', $data);
   exec('C:\"Program Files"\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf ./test.html ./test.pdf > ./log.txt 2>&1');
   
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Comment: You must have run your code multiple times because MaxKeys value higher than 1000 won't get you more than 1000 objects. As stated in MaxKeys documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#listobjects) `Sets the maximum number of keys returned in the response. By default the action returns up to 1,000 key names. The response might contain fewer keys but will never contain more.`

Comment: Okay,  No issues I am not going to use MaxKeys anyway. I am taking the file names from database only. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you tried getPaginator from my answer? I think it would match exactly your need.